# CGI script doesn't run in browser

Tags: perl, cgi

I am making a .cgi file which prints all values from database table on webpage in a table format.The problem is that when I run the file on putty terminal emulator it works fine but when I try to run the file on my browser I get an error message "file not found" even though T typed the correct location of the file on the server.

I can't understand what am I doing wrong? I set my file's permission to chmod 755 * using putty but it's still not working.Is this a problem of file permissions or table structure is wrong for running on browser something else?

Please help...

people.CGI File

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use CGI;
 use DBI;
 use strict;
 #use warnings;
 #use diagnostics;
 print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
 #$q = CGI->new;
 #print  $q->header;
 my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:Demo:localhost";   # Data source name
 my $username = "mint";                 # User name
 my $password = "MINT123";              # Password
 my $dbh;
 my $sth;                          # Database and statement handles
 $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $username, $password);

 $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from people");

 $sth->execute();

 print "<h1>ganesh</h1>";
 print "<table >
 <tr>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>Name of People Involved</th>
 <th>Position</th>
 <th>Roles(A user can have multiple roles)</th>
 <th>Notes</th>
 </tr>";
 while( my $href = $sth->fetchrow_hashref )
 {
   print "<tr>";
   print "<td>$$href{'id'}</td>";
   print "<td>$$href{'name'}</td>";
   print "<td>$$href{'pos'}</td>";
   print "<td>$$href{'role'}</td>";
   print "<td>$$href{'notes'}</td>";
   #print "<td><input type='text' value=\"$$href{'display_name'}\" id =\"dis-$$href{'windows_id'}\" readonly> </td>";
   #print "<td><input type='text' value=\"$$href{'email_id'}\" readonly> </td>";
   print "</tr>";
 }
 print "</table>";

 $sth->finish();
 $dbh->disconnect();
```

Database Table structure...

[image]

Table data...

[image]

Output when i run the file in putty...

[image]

Message when i try running the file on my browser..

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The two answers you have received previously are complete nonsense. You don't need to to use a CGI object in order to run a CGI program. Of course, it makes it easier, but it's not necessary.

The only part of the CGI protocol that your program needs to handle is the Content-Type header. And you're doing that with your print line.

No, your problem is somewhere else completely. But, unfortunately, it's somewhere where we can be of very little help without knowing a lot more. You're getting a file not found error because the web server can't find your code. In other words, the address that you're typing into your browser (128.9.45.170/~pankaj.yadav/Test/cgi/people.cgi) doesn't match a filename on your web server.

This all comes down to how your web server is configured. How are web addresses mapped onto file paths? We don't know. Only your web server administrator will know the answer for sure.

You might get a clue if you look at the web server error log. You'll see a file not found error in the log which will (hopefully) contain the actual file path that the web server is trying to find. And that might help you work out where you should put your CGI program.

Comment: It is for this (and many other) reason that most people don't use CGI.pm to write web apps anymore, even ones that will run under CGI environments. [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) apps are much easier to test and debug (I'm sure Dancer is too) then once its all working if you must deploy under CGI (say Apache) then you KNOW that its server configuration. Just my $0.03 (inflation)

Comment: "Mojolicious apps are much easier to test and debug (I'm sure Dancer is too)" - Basically you want anything that runs on PSGI.

Comment: I have made the above script in notepad++.does it have something to do with EOL conversion of the script??Is a suitable practice to make cgi script directly on server using putty or similar software??even when i'm trying to print simple statements like "hello world" it's not working..

Comment: Lucy, no, it has nothing at all to do with line endings. Your programming is not being run because it is in the wrong place on the web server. I thought I had made that clear.